# TWebBrowser Intercepting Application Events

Tags: browser, c++builder

I have a c++ builder application with a TWebBrowser component.

When I load a specific web page, the application events are intercepted (probably onclick) and sent to the webbrowser.

More detailed: after the page is loaded, if a click a button on the application (not in the web browser), the "OnClick" event of the button is NOT triggered, but the cursor on the webpage moves to the next field.

This occurs exactly the count of 3, after that the OnClick event of the button get triggered again.

(in fact, any click in the app are intercepted and send to the browser)

How I could avoid that?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing code...

Comment: ... and the "specific web page" that is being loaded.

Comment: Sorry, web page available only in intranet...

Comment: About code of the app, there are almost nothing, just a form with 4 componentes: 1) a TEdit to give the URL; 2) a button with WebBrowser1->Navigate(Edit1->Text) on the OnClick event; 3) a WebBrowser and 4) a button with ShowMessage("click ok") on the OnClick event.